# Looping though and executing CSV file

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a CSV file that gets created with long lists of images paths.  E.x. ( del \servername\images\1.2.840.11....really long number.dic )

I want to run though this list and execute each of these lines.  I tried to do some research and saw people using powershell for this.  I wrote a small script but I am not sure how to get powerscript to execute each line of the CSV.

I am sure I just do not know powershell very well but I am open to try any method of going though a CSV and executing the lines.

```
$delList=IMPORT-CSV C:\application\imagesToDelete.csv

FOREACH ($Image in $delList) {
 -- execute each line somehow
}
```

Thanks in advance, this is a one off issue I need to deal with but I have several CSV's containing tens of thousands of images to be deleted

Comment: is it actually a table, with comma separated values, or is it just a list and each line has "del <path to file>"? Does it have a header row?

Comment: it does have a header and in notepad it is just a list.

Comment: You just want to delete the files right? All the lines are "del <path to file>"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let's make this simple and not use Import-CSV. We'll just use Get-Content and skip the header line. Then we use Remove-Item, get a substring of each line starting at the 4th character and going to the end of the line, and remove the result.

```
$Commands = GC $file | Select -Skip 1
$Counter=1
ForEach($Line in $Commands){
    Write-Progress -Activity "Performing commands ($Counter/$($Commands.Count))" -PercentComplete ($Counter/$commands.count*100) -Status "Please wait..."
    Remove-Item $Line.substring(4,$line.length-4)
    $Counter++
}
```

Comment: This looks like it should work but I keep getting "Remove-Item : Cannot find path '\\server\images\<imagename>.dic' because it does not exist

Is there something more I need to know about powershell?  If I copy and paste the line into a CMD it runs fine and sees the file but powershell cannot

any advice?

Comment: Retried this method after I had some free time and this worked great.

I did have to modify the syntax a bit but the core code was exactly what I needed.

Just to add is there anyway to get a count of how many lines it executes?  I got it to wait for the enter key after it finishes so I know it worked but I have no indication of its status while its running.

Thanks again!

Comment: I updated my answer to add a progress bar with Current/Total included.